# Calculate ratio of multi groupby average to groupby average

Tags: python, pandas

I want to produce a Dataframe with as many items `len(hr_avg)` and where the value of the new Dataframe is the hourly average for a month divided by the monthly average for the same month.

The following code is sample code to produce the two data sets that will go into the final calculation. I can loop through hr_avg and calculate item by item, but would prefer a dataframe operation to do it all simultaneously if I can.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

i = pd.date_range('2012-01-01 00:00', '2018-12-31 23:00', freq='H')
x = np.random.randint(1, 100, len(i))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=x, index=i)

hr_avg = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.hour]).mean()
mo_avg = df.groupby([df.index.month]).mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored a bit your column names, joined the monthly averages on the hourly averages and performed the calculation:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

i = pd.date_range('2012-01-01 00:00', '2018-12-31 23:00', freq='H')
x = np.random.randint(1, 100, len(i))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=x, index=i)
hr_avg = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.hour]).mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'month', 'level_1': 'hour', 0: 'hour_avg'}).set_index('month')
mo_avg = df.groupby([df.index.month]).mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'month', 0: 'month_avg'}).set_index('month')
# Join the dataframes so each hour_avg entry has the corresponding mo_avg entry
res_df = hr_avg.join(mo_avg).reset_index().set_index(['month', 'hour'])
# Your calculation - hour_avg divided by monthly_avg
res_df['hour_divided_by_month'] = res_df['hour_avg'] / res_df['month_avg']
```

**Output**

```
                hour_avg    month_avg   hour_divided_by_month
month   hour            
1          0    51.746544   50.378072   1.027164
1          1    53.921659   50.378072   1.070340
1          2    49.649770   50.378072   0.985543
1          3    52.087558   50.378072   1.033933
1          4    48.322581   50.378072   0.959199
```

And so on.

Comment: Looks good, once you change the last line to be `res_df['hour_divided_by_month'] = res_df['hour_avg'] / res_df['month_avg']`